# jQuery Detect How Change Was Triggered

Tags: jquery, html-select, onchange

If I have a select on change event like

```
$('#select').on('change', function (e) {
    //do things
});
```

How can I tell if the user changed this via tabbing to it and typing letters, or by clicking on one of its options?

---

Basically I'm trying to delay an action when the drop down changes, but only when that is caused by someone typing. A click should not warrant a delay, but someone might be typing multiple letters, so I'd like to give them enough time while they type, if that's the case.

Comment: You mean .click() vs .keyPress()?

Comment: @j08691 not necessarily, because me just clicking the drop down then would trigger the click event, and if someone pressed a key that didn't  have an option starting with that letter, a change wouldn't have happened

Comment: @j08691 Another thing I should have noted, is that I have other things that also can trigger the change of this drop down

Comment: create global booleans for `.keyPress` and `.click` then if an `.on('change'` happens you know if one of the above is true...that it was due to that...at the end of a change event set both bools to false..

Comment: Yup, @abc123 that worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var keyPressed = false;
var clicked = false;

$('#select').on('click', function() {
  clicked = true;
})
.on('keyPress', function() {
  keyPressed = true;
})
.on('change', function (e) {
  if (keyPressed) {
    //do things
  }

  keyPressed = false;
  clicked = false;
});
```